# How to remove text from a string in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string

```
var urlString = $('#link1').attr('src');
```

However, it looks like this: //mysite.com/image1_medium.jpeg?v=1233301923

I would like to remove some text so that urlString == '//mysite.com/image1.jpeg'

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [regular expression](http://regex101.com/r/hS2xW0) with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

```
var url = "//mysite.com/image1_medium.jpeg?v=1233301923";
var newUrl = url.replace(/(.*)_medium(.*)\?.*/, "$1$2")
```

Comment: @ArtemPetrosian How am I supposed to know the valid values? I can only answer the question the OP has asked. The question is asking to strip `_medium` and the query string.

Comment: Yea this works. And its always going to be _medium in my case.

Answer (score -1):

```
var new_url = old_url.substring(0, old_url.indexOf('?')).replace("_medium", "");
```

Comment: Was downvoted for not removing _medium. Now it removes _medium.